# Intro.js - any way to prevent closing of tour when clicking outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, intro.js

Wanted to incorporate the intro.js tour plugin but when checking out the plugin, the document didn't highlight any way of preventing the closing of the tour by a click outside the tour section. I would rather have a "End Tour" button which the user can click to end the tour rather than them clicking outside by mistake and then having to start all over again.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Set option `exitOnOverlayClick` to false before you call `start`:

```
introJs().setOptions({
  exitOnOverlayClick: false
}).start();
```

Here are all the available [options](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js#options).